# My heat tape is too long

Tags: electrical, plumbing

I have  about 2 extra feet of  heat tape, after I installed  it. 
What do I do with  extra  length?

The directions say not to coil or double back. My question is with extra length leave it hang or what would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can wrap the tape around the pipe as you install it. You can then add or subtract wraps to adjust the length and make it come out where you want. This works well for just a short amount of slack.

OR

For longer amounts of slack, most heat tape has a bump on the outside of the cable every 18" or so. You can cut the heat tape and install a plug or terminator just after the bump to shorten the tape. Refer to your heat tape's instructions before doing this.

Good luck!